# How can I test for a value in an array in puppet erb template?

Tags: erb, puppet

I have a variable available:

```
$authorized_hosts = ['host1', 'host2']
```

In the erb file:

```
<% if @authorized_keys.host1 %>
  pub key
<% end %>
<% if @authorized_keys.host2 %>
  pub key
<% end %>
```

But I get an error 'undefined method'. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This works apparently :

```
<% if @authorized_keys.include?('host2') %>
```